# Breeze.js returns an error of '; ' (semicolon + space)

Tags: javascript, breeze

I had my Breeze code working with my WCF Data Service yesterday.

Then today, it just stopped working!  When I run the query I get an error message of '; ' (one semicolon and one space) from breeze.

Everything else in the error object looks normal (I am new to breeze, so there may be something to look for that I don't know).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Update:

**When I run my WCF Data Service in the debugger (on my machine) everything works!**  But when I run it hosted on the server, I get the above error.

The only thing I can think of is the cross domain stuff is not working right.  Here is my code for cross domain:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableCrossDomain();
}

static void EnableCrossDomain()
{
    string origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin)) return;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    string method = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
    string headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 204;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I am calling it:

```
function getBags() {

    var bags;
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Bags');

    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceded, _queryFailed);

    function querySucceded(data) {
        bags = data.result;
        logSuccess("Retrieved Bag Data")
        return bags;
    }
}

function _queryFailed(error) {
    logError(config.appErrorPrefix + "Query Failed: " + error.message);
    throw error;
}
```

Is there a better way to allow cross domain calls with Breeze and WCF Data Services?

Comment: Try posting some code, be more detail-oriented, ...

Comment: @user3165879 - There is some code for you.

Comment: Tried `logSuccess("Retrieved Bag Data");` (add `;` after `logSuccess`)? maybe your server "minifiy" codes

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - I added the missing semicolon but it did not help.  (That method is never called when my OData comes from the server anyway, on the error one got called).

Comment: Sounds like a problem in JSON (returned by the server). Could capture the requisition returned using "Web tools" of your browser?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - I fired up fiddler, when I run it locally, there are two calls.  Once for metadata and one for data.  When I run it on the server, there are 4 calls.  The metadata and data calls are preceded by an "OPTIONS" call.  Stepping through the breeze and datajs code shows that this OPTION call confuses it.  (It does not have the headers that are expected like DataServiceVersion.)  In the end the call to Traverse in jsonParser fails because it skips the jsonLightReadPayload call (because it does not have a DataServiceVersion).

Comment: These two "other calls" are indeed unexpected.
Have you tried using the "Profiler" (Firefox) / "Profiles" (webkit-browsers) to investigate?

Comment: Having the same problem (breeze returns ; error when using WCF data services against remote machine). Did you find a solution?  Thanks

Comment: @randbrown - I have not found a solution.  Basically my only hope (now that MS as abandoned WCF Data Services) is that someone takes the open source code and adds in CORS.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem, getting the "; " error message and I'm also using CORS. Breeze is getting an error while trying to find the correct handler for your response. It is not getting a value for "DataServiceVersion" in the returned headers and Breeze is looking for an error message in response.body.message, but that is empty so you only get "; ". Ideally this error report should have some friendly text to tell you that the body message is empty or does not exist.

My fix was to use the Mike Wasson CORS setup using the link provided by Ward in his answer. I had previously been using the SimpleCorsHandler.cs class that is used in the ToDo app sample provided by Breeze, but that was not returning "DataServiceVersion" in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header value for the OPTIONS request. I'm not sure if I could have configured SimpleCorsHandler to fix that; it was eaiser to remove SimpleCorsHandler and use these two lines in the Register method of WebApiConfig.cs instead:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

(See the EnableCorsAttribute docs for more info on the arguments; not a good idea to use "*" for the first one, but just an example here.) Breeze still runs the OPTIONS request for each service call then does a GET request depending on the OPTIONS response which now includes allowing the DataServiceVersion header. The GET request gets the DataServiceVersion header (my value is 3.0) and the error is gone.

Comment: The link to the content by Mike Wasson says it is for "Web API".  I am using WCF Data Services.  As far as I know, they don't mesh.  Are you using Web API or WCF Data Services as your OData Provider?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Web API. I still think that you're issue has to do with allowing the "DataServiceVersion", just not sure how that would be configured in WCF. Can you confirm that the OPTIONS request is returning "dataserviceversion" in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at unintended minification and missing semicolons as suggested by @Guilherme; you may have others besides the one after `logSuccess`.

Please review the steps in "[Debugging Query Result Mysteries](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-result-debugging)", paying special attention to what is actually coming over the wire; browser tools or Fiddler may help here.

It is unlikely that your efforts at implementing CORS are the cause but it's possible. Have you inspected the content of `Response` just before you call `.End()`? Of course you can always work backward from your commits to the point at which the code used to work. You are using version control, yes?

I take it you have eliminated the possibility that your copy of BreezeJS code changed between "yesterday and today".

## CORS

Please reconsider your handrolled CORS efforts. The Web API v.2 provides a CORS facility that is well [described by Mike Wasson](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Did you know about this? If so, is there a reason you're not using it (as it appears that you're not using it)?

Comment: I am using WCF Data Services (not Web API).  I don't think the features described by Mike Wasson will work for WCF Data Services...  I will look at the link you sent and try it out.  The odd thing is that it all works fine if I host the WCF Data Service in the debugger and point to that one with breeze.  I ONLY get this error when going against the exact same code hosted in IIS on a server.

Comment: I fired up fiddler, when I run my WCF Data Service locally, there are two calls that go over the wire from my breeze query.  Once for metadata and one for data.  When I run it on the server, there are 4 calls.  The metadata and data calls are preceded by an "OPTIONS" call.  Stepping through the breeze and datajs code shows that this OPTION call confuses it.  (It does not have the headers that are expected like DataServiceVersion.)  In the end the call to Traverse in jsonParser fails because it skips the jsonLightReadPayload call (because it does not have a DataServiceVersion).

Comment: So you are saying that the query payload comes back but that something on the client-side causes your results to become ";"?  That's too weird. Your mention of DataServiceVersion and jsonLight confuses me as well.  I'm going to guess that, if CORS is contributing to the problem, it is because you are blocked from sending the headers you need across origin. That's something you may want to research. I confess I've not looked into cross-origin OData. Let us know what you learn.

Comment: I suddenly recall that ";" is the way DataJS tells you that it died trying to make sense of a response. Not terribly helpful is it. I fear that you'll have to debug through it until you can identify what it doesn't like about the response.

Comment: I did debug through it.  I don't know enough of CORS to know the details of an OPTIONS call, but somehow I got the data back without the DataServicesVersion in the header.  Since I am using json light (V3), the parsing failed.  If I update datajs to always think it has V3 then it all works fine.  I updated my WCF Data Service to return DataServicesVersion as part of the headers for an OPTIONS call, but somehow datajs did not read that header.

Comment: I confess I don't get how the OPTIONS call sends two calls over the wire (confirmed with fiddler), but in Breeze and datajs it looks like one call.  The weird thing is that in datajs and breeze it has some of **the headers of the OPTIONS call** but has **the data of the GET call**.

Comment: OPTIONS doesn't return data. It's the browser's way of asking the server "will you accept this (forthcoming) request". Even with CORS there are limitations on what headers can be sent across origin; you'll have to look them up as I don't remember them.

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is it looks like they get merged.  I have some OPTIONS Headers with the GET Data.